# Makefile target references Makefile

Tags: makefile

I just discovered this line in a makefile:

```
%: Makefile
```

To me, that says *"to make any target, you need this makefile"*, which strikes me as somewhat obvious.

Is there any situation in which this is not a no-op?

Comment: It will cause targets to get rebuilt when the makefile changes. If there was a target in the makefile that could update the makefile that would also cause that to run (though I don't know if that would cause a make restart or not so it might only apply to the next run).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Etan commented, this will cause every target to be rebuilt whenever the Makefile changes. This is necessary so that anytime you make a change in the build configuration parameters the target will be rebuilt. Otherwise make won't know to rebuild with the new configuration.